# Is the blkarray package compatible with Xetex and amsmath?

Tags: amsmath, arrays

Running xelatex on the file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}
\begin{blockarray}{c}
    1
\end{blockarray}
\end{document}
```

gives the error

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/blkarray/blkarray.sty)
(./test.aux)
! Incompatible list can't be unboxed.
<argument> \BA@first@box 

l.9 \end{blockarray}
```

[Upon removing the reference to amsmath, the file compiles.]

Why does this error occur? Is it possible to use the blkarray package together with amsmath and xelatex?

Thank you.

Comment: unrelated to xelatex, you get the same with (pdf)latex as well. Interesting. Who wrote that?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Some rabble-rouser. The documentation provides some form of life-long anonymity: "Warning! This style option is in the early stages of development." (dated 1999). The author seems to be listed as *inactive*. Sad that they just drop support like that, without notice...

Comment: @Werner but note that 1999 date just refers to a change of email, the comment dates from 1992

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: ...in true rabble-rouser fashion.

Comment: I updated `blkarray` on ctan to fix this, first update this millennium:-) http://www.ctan.org/pkg/blkarray

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nice MWE. It turns out amsmath tramples on box 0 (as it has a right to do, really) but it was unfortunate as blkarray was doing the same thing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\makeatletter
\newbox\BA@first@box
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\begin{blockarray}{c}
    1
\end{blockarray}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/dpctex/source/detail?r=95

Answer (score 3):

You'll have no problem if you write your `blockarray` in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{blockarray}{[c\}}
    1\\-1
\end{blockarray} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]